# Root cause & Propagation of Exception in SAP Cloud SDK

Tags: exception, sap-cloud-sdk

Suppose I have a supplier and some exception occurs while invoking get method of that supplier.

```
 Supplier<> supplier = () -> getSomething();
 ResilienceDecorator.executeSupplier( //Edit 1 - Could be ResilienceDecorator.executeCallable
                supplier,
                resilienceConfiguration,
                throwable -> {
                   log.error("Exception occured", throwable);
                   return null;
                });
```

Edit 1 - Also same for `ResilienceDecorator.executeCallable`.
I need a consistent API to know what went wrong during execution i.e. What was the **checked** **exception** (**Edit 1 -  or Unchecked exception**)  causing the failure so I can 
 handle business logic. The throwable is not root cause of exception or whatever the supplier had thrown.

If we do not provide a throwable function like above then
 every exception is wrapped in a `ResilienceRuntimeException` and we need a chain of `getCause().getCause()` to know what went wrong. This is internal to sdk which might change. Again a consistent API is needed.

Is there any alternative & consistent way to know what exception the supplier is throwing? I might need to bubble it up or write a user friendly message based on the exception occured, depending upon buisness logic.

Edit 1- 
An example of my current situation.

```
Supplier<MatDocItm> supplier = () -> {
        ErpHttpDestination erpHttpDestination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination(S4_SYSTEM).asHttp().decorate(DefaultErpHttpDestination::new);
        return new CustomCommand(erpHttpDestination, params).execute();     
    }

    try {
        MatDocItm = ResilienceDecorator.executeSupplier(
                supplier,
                configuration
        );
    } catch (ResilienceRuntimeException e) {
        throw new ReadException("Failed to read from SAP S/4HANA", e);
    }
```

The supplier can throw runtime exceptions and based on these exceptions I want to give a User friendly error message with proper description.

The supplier can throw a `DestinationAccessException` (which is runtime exception) if a destination cannot be accessed, is not configured correctly, or does not fulfill certain prerequisites.
Not only the exceptions occured in supplier, I have `TimeLimiterConfiguration` & if timeout occurs then a `TimeoutException` can be thrown.

For above MatDocItm example the `ResilienceRuntimeException.getCause()` will give `com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.exception.ThreadContextExecutionException`. `ResilienceRuntimeException.getCause().getCause()` will reveal exception that actually caused the error i.e `DestinationAccessException`. Now ThreadContextExecutionException is internal to sdk and can change if sdk implementation changes. Will this implementation detail remain frozen and never change in future or is there any alternative way to get the root cause?

Comment: Your question makes an incorrect assumption. A supplier **can not** throw any checked exceptions, as the `Supplier` interface does not declare any checked exceptions. Consider updating your question (e.g. using `executeCallable` instead). Still, in general I recommend using the approach Alexander pointed out below.

Comment: Sorry, OP. I think I misunderstood your question. You want the original _non-cloud-sdk_ exception, no matter what type. I would understand the reasoning but I don't directly see the advantage? Can you give a concrete use case where this was necessary? (and the below answer will not suffice?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AlexanderDümont. Yes for me to know original non-cloud-sdk exception, will be the requirement. For me the advantage would be simple way to know what exactly went wrong so I can return a fallback value or react accordingly.
For example, the Project Reactor API https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/project-reactor-error-handling-examples onErrorReturn method seems handy. Having said that, I think the below answer is good & will suffice, although I am on a 3.9 version of lang3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [`ExceptionUtils.throwableOfType`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#throwableOfType-java.lang.Throwable-java.lang.Class-) for matching exception type and sub classes.
Alternatively [`ExceptionUtils.throwableOfThrowable`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#throwableOfThrowable-java.lang.Throwable-java.lang.Class-) for matching exact type only.
The utility class already provided by dependency `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.10`

Example:

```java
@Nullable
YourException cause = ExceptionUtils.throwableOfType(throwable, YourException.class);
```

You can handle the nullable result in an If statement.

As a fan of fluent APIs, I would rather go with `java.util.Optional` or `io.vavr.control.Option`.

Comment: Many thanks, these utility methods will save lot of development and testing efforts for me! Thanks for the Optional suggestion as well, cherry on top :)